# How change time in docker container, if you need test cron tasks?

Tags: python, linux, docker, cron, celery

I have Python project (Flask, Celery, Redis, MySql) . 
And run this in Docker containers.

Tasks must be executed at a specified time:
00:00, 06:00, */1, */3, */6, other .

How i can test this?
the desired result:

1. create task with test data.
2. after task success, need change system time, for example: 23:59:50 .
3. wait 00:01 .
4. check system database, if all data is valid .

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: DevOps tell me, maybe we need https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime, but, but it seems we do not quite fit

Comment: I'm wondering how to do it correctly
maybe I'm somewhere wrong